How to check decimal values from 0 till 100?
On Laravel 11 site I need to check decimal values from 0 till 100(with 2 decimals possible) and I do it with rules :
['required', 'numeric', 'between:0,100'],

OR
required|numeric|min:0.01|max:100

but both not works. Which rules are valid ?
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",


"but both not works. ". Please edit your question and describe in detail what this means. Which one doesn't work? How doesn't it work? Please include input with expected vs actual output.

See docs: Laravel validation rule "between" shows between:0,100 should work. If it doesn't it is probably something else. Please give more details like error messages, data you tested with, output, etc.

[
    'required',
    'numeric',
    'regex:/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$|^100(\.00?)?$/',
    'between:0,100',
]


regex:/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$|^100(\.00?)?$/: This regular expression allows numbers from 0 to 100, with up to two decimal places.

^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$: Matches numbers from 0 to 99.99.
|^100(\.00?)?$: Allows the number 100, optionally followed by .0 or .00.


between:0,100: Ensures that the number is within the range 0 to 100.



You can use this, too
$request->validate([
    'your_field_name' => [
        'required',
        'numeric',
        'between:0,100',
        'regex:/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/'
    ],
], [
    'your_field_name.regex' => 'The :attribute must be a number with up to two decimal places.',
]);


You can do this using regex way
$request->validate([
'field_name' => [
    'required',
    'numeric',
    'between:0,100',
    'regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
    ],
 ]);

If you need this without using regex, you can follow the steps below
Create Custom Validation Rule
php artisan make:rule DecimalPrecision

Implement Rule Logic
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class DecimalPrecision implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return is_numeric($value) && $value >= 0 && $value <= 100 && preg_match('/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/', $value);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be a number between 0 and 100 with up to 2 decimal places.';
    }
}

Use Custom Rule
use App\Rules\DecimalPrecision;

$request->validate([
    'value' => ['required', 'numeric', new DecimalPrecision()],
]);

